# Passing JSON data url instead of data internally in nvd3-Angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

It looks like AnjularJS-nvd3 is using the JSON data for their charts internally and i would like to know whether is it possible to pass an external JSON data url and use those data in charts. I don't know where to start.

Thank you in advance.